# Getting Multiple errors when performing update with "apt-get update"

Tags: apt, updates

For some reason my ubuntu has become very slow because of apt-daily-upgrade.service taking 45.63s. Main reason being getting a whole list of errors and not being able to update.

````
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9658E8044A3AA3D6
E: The repository 'http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.```
````

Comment: I picked one & looked up what release it supports (pasting URL from your messages); and could quickly detect it was unmaintained...  PPAs are 3rd party sources, so checks to see they are appropriate for your system, maintained, not security risks etc. is all on you.  Did you do any checks?  https://launchpad.net/~docky-core  (I'd consider a PPA that hasn't been touched since 2015 a potential security risk, let alone the lack of support for your release etc....)

Comment: The `apt-daily-upgrade` is Unattended Upgrades running the equivalent of `apt upgrade`, (NOT `apt update`, which is done by a different job), and 45 seconds is a typical amount of time required to do the job. Unattended Upgrades is designed to be unobtrusive -- it should not be noticeably slowing your system.

Comment: apt upgrade also gives the same error. Also the question by @guiverc is not helpful. Doesn't remove errors.

Comment: Did you remove the unsupported PPA.  A user on your system with `sudo` rights added a PPA that provides support for 14.04/15.04 on your system running 20.04; ie. a user error that requires you to fix by removal of the line added by the user with `sudo` rights that added the inappropriate PPA. That duplicate tells you how to do it (it's not the only fix; myself I'd just correct it with `vi` or `vim`.. but you need to adjust the commands for the PPA/sources you added & not just copy/paste the command from that case which was for a different release & different PPA. I suspect that's your issue.

Comment: Yea removing the ppa using the software updater did the job. Thanks for your help @guiverc.